# How can I get just the C# parser (Syntax Tree) extracted from Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to pull in the Roslyn source code to a Unity 3D video game that will have live C# editing in it.  I'm wanting the Syntax Tree, to help with debugging, formatting and analysis, and was originally planning to roll my own parser for this purpose.  But if I can extract Roslyn's syntax tree to execute in Unity, that would make things a lot easier.

However, I have probably put 12 hours of time into trying to reduce the Roslyn project down (see escapades here: https://codavore.blogspot.com/2019/11/c-parser-part-2.html) and I haven't succeeded in reducing the project.  I.e. removing the VB parts affect the dual test cases for C#/VB, and removing one superfluous thing affects a dozen others.

Anyone have advice for extracting out jut the C# Syntax Tree's source code?

Comment: Can you explain why using this nuget package is insufficient? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/3.3.1

Comment: This is for a Unity project (per the first line). Unity projects don't like Nuget, because the project setup is managed by Unity.  I.e. CSProj (and other files) is rewritten by Unity every time I make a file change in Unity. I'm trying to extract just the source code from the open source side.  

I did try installing the CS Parser from your link, but couldn't get any of the samples to work, or namespaces to show up after install. Usually I can still use Nuget to install something, it just won't be retained. But here, immediately after running nuget, I don't have access to the name spaces. :(

Comment: I had not even seen the nuget package, I've literally only been finding reference to the source on GitHub.  And as the previous reply mentions, I can't rely on Nuget, so I don't tend to bother with it.

Comment: Roslyn is not designed to be distributed as source. you should be able to use the parser by included the nuget library as a managed plugin as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019#add-packages-from-nuget-to-a-unity-project). `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText`should do what you want from there

Comment: OK, got it, with some bugs.  First, I had to remove it from Visual Studio (which did not work when it was installed on the Unity project.) 2) install nuget for Unity. 3) install the same link you gave. 4) delete duplicate/versioned DLL's and language support since it confused Unity. - This cleared it up enough that I was able to get an extraction out.  There were still bugs, like some of the analyzers, which unity didn't like and unloaded, but the parsing still seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

I was originally hoping to pull in source code, but per @Jonathon Marolf's comments, I attempted to pull it in via nuget. But Unity overwrites most of what nuget does, anytime I change the files, so that didn't work. To get around this, I found and installed [NuGet for Unity](https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity). Then ran the nuget "Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp -Version 3.3.1".

Of course this broke the project, because its designed for VS projects, not Unity. I had to delete the duplicate DLLs, and also all the language support files. It still had an error with a couple analysis dlls that were unloaded when trying to run, but it was able to parse out part of the source code I passed it.